# How to use Bower Libraries in NetBeans?

Tags: netbeans, bower, netbeans-8.1

In the NetBeans 8.1 the bower_components folder is stored outside of the Site Root folder.

Therefore, I can't load css or js files from the bower_components into my html.

So, how to load files from the Bower Libraries?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One should to copy required files into site folder.

It can be done manually or via gulp and main-bower-files plugin.

sample gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var mainBowerFiles = require('main-bower-files');


gulp.task('mainJS', function () {
    return gulp.src( mainBowerFiles('**/*.js') )
            .pipe( gulp.dest('public_html/libs/js') );
});
gulp.task('mainLess', function () {
    return gulp.src( mainBowerFiles('**/*.less') )
            .pipe( gulp.dest('public_html/libs/less') );
});
gulp.task('mainCSS', function () {
    return gulp.src( mainBowerFiles('**/*.css') )
            .pipe( gulp.dest('public_html/libs/css') );
});

gulp.task('main-bower-files', ['mainJS', 'mainLess', 'mainCSS']);
```

Comment: When creating a new HTML5/JS application in Netbeans 8.1 you have the option to create a bower.json file as part of the wizard. If you do this, Netbeans creates another file called ".bowerrc" which contains a reference to the bower_components folder. Now, whenever you add a package using bower, it will be available within the Netbeans project without having to copy it manually or with gulp.